# Why does Excel display incorrect modified times when listing recent files?

Tags: microsoft-excel, metadata

When I try to open a file in the recent files list in Excel I'll often find that a workbook I worked on yesterday or the day before is not in the list.  When I expand the list to include older workbooks I'll find the workbook I was looking for, but the Date modified will show as several days prior to when I last worked on it.

Why does Excel seem to get the Date modified wrong for recent workbooks?

Here's an example, highlighting the Date modified as seen by Excel and the Date modified as seen by File Explorer.  The File Explorer Date modified is correct:

[image: Date modified for Excel and File Explorer compared]

Comment: Dates are working fine here:  Excel, Word then checked against Windows File Explorer.   Try doing a Full Repair from Control Panel, Office , restart and see if that works. I think Excel might have a date format option. Check to see that this is correct for your system.

Comment: Based on the picture, did the File Explorer was filtered by Name.?

Comment: The File Explorer isn't filtered.  However, it is sorted by name.

Comment: I have been aware of this issue Excel 2019/365 on Windows 10 for ages (>1 year) and finally decided to Google it today because it's still there and it is deeply concerning to think work wasn't saved. The problem is real; wrong timestamp shown on Recent & Pinned tabs, happens every time Excel is started; clearing Excel's file cache  has no effect.  It even gets the date wrong (by several days), so it is not a timezone effect. The Excel "modified" value can be earlier OR later than the OS "modified" value!